# Does anyone have any idea about any songCatcher library for Linux? or any idea on how to use "Audio-Ofa-Util-0.04"?

Tags: audio-fingerprinting

Does anyone have any idea about any songCatcher library for Linux? songCatcher is based on the acoustic fingerprints.

I managed to find one "Audio-Ofa-Util-0.04" but I'm facing problem in using it.  Or if someone can help me understand its usage. 
Like: > how can I pass an audio file to this tool.

> Any specific command for its usage etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out these other posts on SO:

- [Is there a free database or web service api for music information (albums, artists, tracks)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988760/is-there-a-free-database-or-web-service-api-for-music-information-albums-artist)
- [Musicbrainz fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992505/musicbrainz-fingerprinting)

The ubuntu package contains an example program using PUIDs* to identify songs in WAVE or MP3 format.

[*] http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/How_PUIDs_Work