# Is there a free database or web service api for music information (albums, artists, tracks)?

Tags: database, open-source

I need to look up artist/album/track information for song titles.

Is there a free database I could download or a open source web service/api I could use?

Comment: You should ask at http://opendata.stackexchange.com this question would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the last.fm api at http://www.last.fm/api.

If that doesn't work for you, you can look at the various APIs listed in this search result:
http://www.programmableweb.com/category/music/api

This is a Silverlight tutorial, but since this is an HTTP REST API, it could seem agnostic to you to get started: http://www.devx.com/VisualStudio/Article/40158.

Comment: I've used last.fm and it was pretty nice for a couple of years. Recently it has turned to garbage - does not return data in many instances. Many functional pieces are broken. Still looking for an alternative to switch to.

Comment: While I am glad that it helped the poster of this question, this answer is old enough in "Internet years" that really there are probably far better places to look now.  Sorry about the answer being stale, but not sure how StackOverflow deals with that.

Comment: `last.fm` is worthless for album info. It does not even return the release date, e.g., Metallica's multi-platinum self-titled album.

Answer (score 23):

I'd go with musicbrainz.

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/libmusicbrainz

Answer (score 14):

I would personnally recommend [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com), which is free and doesn't limit the *per day* usage. However, it limits the amount of requests to one per second per IP address.

The [API](https://www.discogs.com/developers/) is quite clear and documented. It uses JSON over HTTP, and has wrappers for various programming environnements (Python, Ruby, Perl, .NET, PHP).

Plus, it has data about a massive amount of artists, releases and labels.

Comment: Updated API Link: https://www.discogs.com/developers/

Answer (score 9):

Yes! [The Echo Nest](http://the.echonest.com). Pretty hot startup outside Boston that just got more funding. Their API lets you search by artist, album, track, and more.

Comment: and their funding just seems to have exhausted. it goes 404.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link. That said, I'm kinda surprised that `echonest.com` (without subdomain) doesn't resolve. Also, they were bought by Spotify, so I guess that funding is no longer an issue. :-)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: Pro: Echonest is free and easy to use. Contra: Echonest doesn't know anything about albums.

Comment: And link is not working again.

Answer (score 0):

FreeDB is free, but may or may not have an API. It is user-generated content.

**http://www.freedb.org/**

And apparently [Gracenote](http://www.gracenote.com/solutions/) is the new CDDB (but probably not free). I guess they finally figured out that they didn't want to limit their database to CDs.